# Create a build for Node.js (fastify) server to electron app

Tags: node.js, electron, electron-builder, fastify

1. I am using **node js 10.15.0** along with **fastify** server int it.
2. I am also using normal **public** folder shared in the project.
3. Below is the project hierarchy.

[image]

> **NOTE**: This code when started, starts as a standalone server which also servers UI.

I tried ***electron-packager/ electron-builder*** but I am not getting desired build as executable like **.exe** etc.

**Question:**

Can anyone please guide me through how can I achieve creating a build from node.js pure server code using fastify.

Comment: What you got after you ran ```electron-builder```?